# Use case for calculating the geometric distance between points in two separate GIS layers

Tags: sql, distance, st-distance

I am trying to calculate the distance between each transformer in one view layer and its respective upline substation (one per transformer) in another view layer. The upline substation is listed in the attribute field of the transformer layer and substation layer but I'm not quite sure how to reference those fields in the query. I managed to successfully calculate the shortest distance to a substation for each transformer, but I would like to be able to get distances to specific corresponding substations only. Here is some code that I wrote...the syntax within the STDistance function is incorrect but I left it there because it may help explain the logic of what I'm trying to do.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.v_BC_Utilities_Electric_Transformer AS
DECLARE @
SELECT 1000000 + mo.OBJECTID AS OBJECTID, replace(mo.wmUplineSource, ' ', '_') AS Upline_Source, Data_Authority = 'Maryville Electric Department', mo.Shape, ROUND(mo.Shape.STDistance(ms.Shape=mo.wmUplineSource)*0.000189393939,2) AS Mi_To_Nearest_Substation
FROM bcgis.dbo.TRANSFORMER mo, v_BC_Utilities_Electric_Substation AS ms 
WHERE mo.wmIsDead = 'false'  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2000000 + ao.OBJECTID AS OBJECTID, replace(ao.wmUplineSource, ' ', '_') AS Upline_Source, Data_Authority = 'Alcoa Electric Department', ao.Shape, ROUND(ao.Shape.STDistance(als.Shape=mo.wmUplineSource)*0.000189393939,2) AS Mi_To_Nearest_Substation
FROM ALCOA.dbo.TRANSFORMER ao, v_BC_Utilities_Electric_Substation AS als 
WHERE ao.wmIsDead = 'false'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3000000 + OBJECTID AS OBJECTID, Upline_Source = '', Data_Authority = 'Ft Loudoun Electric Co-op' , Shape, Mi_To_Nearest_Substation = -9999 
FROM bcgis.dbo.TRANSFORMERBANK fo 
WHERE Placement = 1;
```